# Media Query Not Running

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I create a website which is working completely.

I put media query..as per earlier responsive website, but it not work in my website.

this my website www.itztotalsolutions.us, i tried to add media query for make responsive but there is a no media query effects in mobile or ipad.. here i mentioned that i have problems with mobile and ipad website look.. it seems like a normal website as per we seen in desktop not as i write css for mobile and Ipad... means it not detect a device resolutions.

Here is code. In header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

In style.css:

```
body, html { height: 100%;}
body {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
    background:url(images/main-full-bg.jpg) repeat #F60;
    background-size:cover;
}

...etc.... all CSS for pages.. after it

/* ipad portrait */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 980px) {
    body { min-width: 768px; }
    .shell { max-width: 748px; }
    #navigation ul li { padding-left: 24px; font-size: 15px; }
    .header-top { padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; }
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    body { min-width: 320px; }
    .shell { max-width: 320px; }
    .header .shell { padding:0; background: url(images/m-header-shell.jpg) no-repeat 0 0; }

    .header-top { padding: 0px 0 0px 0; }
    #logo { margin: 0 auto; float: none; display: block; }
}
@media only screen and ( max-width: 767px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-resolution: 240dpi) {

    #logo a { background: url(images/logo@2x.png) no-repeat 0 0; -webkit-background-size: 142px 57px; -moz-background-size: 142px 57px; background-size: 142px 17px; }
    #navigation { background: url(images/navigation@2x.png) no-repeat 0 0; -webkit-background-size: 298px 32px; -moz-background-size: 298px 32px; background-size: 298px 32px; }
    #navigation a.nav-btn span { background: url(images/nav-arr@2x.png) no-repeat 0 0; -webkit-background-size: 10px 15px; -moz-background-size: 10px 15px; background-size: 10px 15px; }
    .pagination a { background: url(images/pagination@2x.png) no-repeat 0 1px; -webkit-background-size: 18px 40px; -moz-background-size: 18px 40px; background-size: 18px 40px; }
    .main section { background: url(images/section@2x.png) no-repeat center bottom; -webkit-background-size: 300px 10px; -moz-background-size: 300px 10px; background-size: 300px 10px; }
}
```

I checked that when I run in mobile it seems CSS is running from default CSS not from query CSS.

Please help me to solve this

Comment: What's with the title?

Comment: Could you describe the problem in a bit more detail? "it not work in my website" isn't a great description. What do you expect this code to do, and what does it actually do?

Comment: You are trying media queries in IE8? What browser do you use?

Comment: I just tested with Chrome's developer tools and it appears the styles are properly applied from Media Queries. You should try and refresh your browser (may be the old css file is cached)

Comment: @samirprajapati: hi Samir. You can edit your question to include those details, then everyone will see them more easily.

Comment: How about providing your document's html so we can take a deeper look ? Can you detail the context where your sitiation can be tested ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you have a misplaced `{}` ?
Check your CSS here: http://csslint.net/